# javafx pane.getChildren().remove(Node nd) is not working

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8

I've got a Pane with some elements on it. My program sometimes adds Elements and should also remove them.
But when I try to remove elements, they just stay there. 
I already tried to log this case and the program returns always true when I call this method.

```
public void removeAddedElements() {
    for (Node addedElement : addedElements) {
        if (parent.getChildren().contains(addedElement)) {
            parent.getChildren().remove(addedElement); //this returns true
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a sidenote: There's no need to invoke `contains` prior to `remove`.

Comment: I know...otherwise the remove would just return false

Comment: We’ll need to see the code that adds the Nodes to `parent` and the code that adds Nodes to `addedElements`.

Comment: public void addElementToBoard(Node element) {
        addedElements.add(element);
        parent.getChildren().add(element);
    }

Comment: Could add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This cannot be solved without a [MCVE]. There is (fairly obviously) nothing at all wrong with the code you have posted: if it's not working the problem lies in other parts of your code.

Comment: After restarting my computer the problem never occurred again...don't know why